# Recaptcha Validator in .NET 1.1 project

Tags: .net, validation, .net-1.1, recaptcha

I am trying to use an old version of the Recaptcha Validator on a .net 1.1 project, which can be found here: http://recaptcha.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet-old/src/Recaptcha/

The code I have is very similar to an example that can be found at the above link:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<recatpcha:RecaptchaValidator ID="RecaptchaValidator1" runat="server" Theme="Clean" PublicKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" PrivateKey="xxxxxxxxxx" ControlToValidate="EmailAddress"></recatpcha:RecaptchaValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

The behavior I would like is simple: on page load, the user is presented with a field to enter their email address, a captcha to complete, and a submit button. On submit, if no user is found in our database with that email address, or the captcha is answered incorrectly, a new captcha is displayed along with a appropriate error message. Otherwise, they will receive an email about how to reset their password.

The main issue is that the captcha does not display on page load. When I hit the submit button however, triggering Page.Validate(), the page is reloaded and the captcha is displayed.

Based on this, I figured I'd try a different approach and call Page.Validate() in the page load event to get the captcha to show up initially. This almost worked: the captcha showed up on first page load, but when an invalid email is submitted along with a correct captcha answer, the captcha disappears when the page is reloaded, but of course, the email cannot be sent.

How can I either force the captcha to be rendered when the page is hit initially, or, prevent the captcha from being submitted when an invalid email address is entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not pretty, but I got it working.

Since using the RecaptchaValidator tag didn't work the way I wanted it to, I used the recaptcha AJAX API (http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html) to embed the widget on the page thusly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Recaptcha.create("<public key>",
        "ReCaptcha", {
        theme: "clean",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    });
});
```

Then, since all the data need to validate with the recaptcha servers (challenge, publickey, etc. more info here: http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/) is in the POST, I instantiated a new RecaptchaValidator, set the remaining properties, and called the method to validate the user response.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    RecaptchaValidator RecaptchaValidator1 = new RecaptchaValidator();
    RecaptchaValidator1.Page = this;
    RecaptchaValidator1.PrivateKey = "<private key>";
    RecaptchaValidator1.PublicKey = "<public key>";

    bool CaptchaPassed = RecaptchaValidator1.ValidateUserResponse();

    if (CaptchaPassed)
    {    
        //hide the captcha, do some stuff
    }       
}
```

Admittedly a bit hacky, but it got the job done.

NOTE - I mentioned this in the question, but just to reiterate: the server side code for this uses the old, .NET 1.1 compatible recaptcha plug-in. The link to the code for the plug-in is in the question. I have embarrassingly low rep, and can't use any more hyperlinks >.<